# I want to convert an activity in a service

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, service, android-activity

I want create a service that do the same that my activity, but I have some problems.
For example in my activity I have two objects of JavaCameraView which initialize with a layout:

```
auxiliar = (ControlCamera) findViewById(R.id.tutorial5_activity_java_surface_view);
auxiliar2 = (ControlCamera) findViewById(R.id.tutorial5_activity_java_surface_view2);
```

---

```
<com.uvigo.gti.PictoDroidLite.ControlCamera
        android:id="@+id/tutorial5_activity_java_surface_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        opencv:camera_id="front"
        opencv:show_fps="true" />

    <com.uvigo.gti.PictoDroidLite.ControlCamera
        android:id="@+id/tutorial5_activity_java_surface_view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        opencv:camera_id="back"
        opencv:show_fps="true" />
```

How do i have to do to inicialite these objects in my service? Because in a service I can not use the function findViewById.

Thanks

Comment: services doesn't have an UI , they are designed to be executed in the background with no UI.

Comment: So, to open frontal or back camera. What do i have to do?